MySQL Query stuck in executing wait/io/table/sql/handler in AWS RDS
I have a query
SELECT `property_category_name` as `property_category`
FROM `listings`
WHERE (
community_name LIKE '%Sun%'
)
AND `listings`.`property_for` = 'sale'
LIMIT 

Now when i am executing this query manually it takes almost 0.002 seconds and return with No Row as result. Now the issue comes when i run the same query from my php code.
it gets stuck there
show full processlist

It shows the below

and it will stay like this until i restart the server or kill this process, in reality it shouldn't take this much time and should give no row as result.
I didn't find any solution for this but the other thing i noticed in sys-> x$processlist table is below. It is the same query but in wait/io/table/sql/handler state.
I am attaching the screenshot of the processlist table below

it will stay like this until i restart the database or kill the process manually. I tried to find a solution but nothing worked. Database is hosted on AWS RDS mysql 8.0. Below is the screenshot of the configuration.


Hav you look at the output from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;


ROW OPERATIONS
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=815, Main thread ID=23046028986112 , state=sleeping
Number of rows inserted 199246, updated 37665, deleted 92, read 4041632251
37.02 inserts/s, 23.67 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 1490862.77 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 150, updated 370, deleted 146, read 31117
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 11.15 reads/s
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
This is the footer response I get

sorry, I'm out. I don't see any reason why this doesn't work. I think that you also set an index, the rest (LIKE) results in a FULL TABLE SCAN on the rest of the table anyway. Good luck, I'll keep an eye on it out of interest

All these fields that are being used in that query is already added as indexed.

What i doubt is an issue in the configuration of AWS RDS MySQL. Because when i run this query straight to mysql it is working fine but when i pass it via Code it freeze and due to the wait and queues all other queries stop working and as a result the website crash.
